# what does "predominantly" modify?

Tags: modifiers

In the following sentence, does "predominantly" modify "Afghan" or "Afghan refugees"?

> A total of 60 visas were granted to **predominantly** Afghan refugees.

Comment: I think it needs more context to indicate whether the topic is visas, Afghans or refugees. But at face value the placing of 'to' suggests that 'predominantly' applies to 'Afghan'.

Comment: It seems clear enough to me that most of the 60 came from Afghanistan.

Comment: Without more context it's ambiguous. The adverb "predominantly" could be modifying either the adjective "Afghan" or the whole NP "Afghan refugees".